# Accessing type of interface implementer in interface methods

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
public interface IMy<T>
{
    T Implementer
    {
        get;
    }
}
public class MyClass : IMy<MyClass>
{
    ...
}
```

But what I want is this:

```
public interface IMy
{
    I Implementer
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

Please accept that for some ca-razy reason I need an interface that defines a method that returns in the type of the implementer. No? Okay, suppose it's something like an XML explorer, so call my interface `ITree` for example.

Interfaces primarily help me organize (separate), but when I have one that requires I rely on a convention, it seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: The first snippet is generally the way to go to solve the "Parent needs to define a generic interface with subclass's types" problem. I do not understand why it doesn't work for you. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Irfy Well, the convention I mentioned is clearly that you have to implement on MyClass with IMy<MyClass>, but nothing prevents you from implementing with IMy<OtherClass>. I probably misused the forum to gripe about a vague "dirty" feeling, but your comment is a valid answer.

Comment: Just as a note to anyone who might land here -- my motivation for asking the question had a lot to do with unfamiliarity with generic interface type parameter contravariance. What I asked for seems more obscure in retrospect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be able to say "The interface should know who implements it, and automatically provide the implementer's type in its definition, to be inherited by the implementer"? Like

```
public interface IMy
{
    ImplicitImplementerType SomeProperty
    {
        get;
    }
}
```

I'm pretty sure that is impossible. Such a thing may be achieved in more dynamic languages though (I'm guessing here).

Comment: That's what I would have liked because the dirty feeling actually propagates in my code as unnecessary-looking code (interface hierarchies, extension methods). I'll get used to it.

Comment: I suggest you to "feel grateful" for already knowing this actually [very useful pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) :-) Many programmers write bad code not knowing how to solve contravariance problems.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot statically specify such a return type. In C# (and in the CLR) there is no "thistype". But you can find it out at runtime:

```
var thisType = this.GetType()
```

Since I don't think this is what you need, I have to inform you that it is not possible to do what you want.

Of course, the first code snippet of yours *would* work but you don't want that.

Comment: Good answer, but I don't want to take the dynamic plunge, and you correctly perceived that it's a whim. Someone else jumped in with a comment. Thank you.